# Roles in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a view in schema A using snapshots in schema B. I was trying to assign roles to the view. But it doesnt allow me to. It says there is some error related to access to the tables from the snapshots.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, like the command you issued and the error codes that resulted?

Answer (score 2):

Schema B needs to grant schema A select on the snapshots "WITH GRANT OPTION" ("WITH ADMIN OPTION" is only for system privileges, not object privileges):

```
grant select on TABLE_NAME to A with grant option;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei..  That is what I was thinking but for some reason got the 2 options flipped.

Answer (score 1):

Schema B needs to grant schema A select on the snapshots "with grant option" for schema A to be able to pass on the grants to other schemas/roles.

```
GRANT SELECT ON my_table TO a WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Edited per Andrei's correction.  (Andrei's answer should be the one accepted though!)